# How are methods called that prepare/alter some data and then pass it on

Tags: naming, methods, naming-standards

I am currently trying to name a method that prepares/alters some input data, then passes it on, and I'm wondering if there is a naming scheme for such methods.

Concretely, I have a reusable UI component that will copy its contents on user interaction. Users of the component should have the ability to pass a method to the component that will be called before the content is copied to give them a chance to alter the content copied. Made-up code example:

```
class MyComponent {
    
    var beforeCopying: Method

    private func onCopy() {
        let copiedContent = beforeCopying(originalContent)
        putIntoClipboard(copiedContent)
    }
}

... in a user of MyComponent...

let component = MyComponent()
component.beforeCopying = { (originalContent) 
    return originalContent.reversed()
}

... in another user of MyComponent...


let component = MyComponent()
component.beforeCopying = { (originalContent) 
    return originalContent.shuffled()
}
```

The question is: What would be a good name for `beforeCopying` that indicates that this is meant to be set by the outside, and indicates when this is called / what it does?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - the component function doesn't need to be named after the caller context, because it can be reused from different contexts.

From the above sample, the `onCopy()` function name clearly states that whatever it encapsulates is / should be called upon the copy operation, so any operation happening inside such function doesn't necessarily need to carry the same context on their names. Imagine sometime in the future you need to extend this program to perform the same kind of data transformation also before pasting (or any other operation). You could still call all or some of the inner functions to accomplish this, without the functions themselves needing to care who the caller was.

Based on this and looking at the implementation, it would be safe to say that `beforeCopying(originalContent)` could be easily called `reverse(originalContent)`.

Comment: I see your point, but think I haven't made clear exactly what I'm trying to achieve: MyComponent doesn't know the kind of transformation performed within `beforeCopying`. The whole idea is that the outside can perform an arbitrary transformation that suits the current context. However, it can be guaranteed by MyComponent that `beforeCopying` will be called only before copying, since that's the purpose of the method.

I will alter the current example to include this.

Comment: Ok, if I understood correctly, the method exposed from your component should be simply called `onCopy()` then.